# How to reset a variables value (delete - undefined - null)

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I read if you declare a variable you can not delete it.
If you leave it undeclared you can.
I also read if you do not declare a variable it can cause issues later.

Certain lints I have used have pointed out declared and undeclared issues in some of the stuff I have written, to stop the reporting of these issues and based off of all the information I have read thus far, I have opted to declare all my variables.

Now here is where this becomes confusing for me.

I am trying to build a random name generator that utilizes a `Math.random` routine, when I try to recycle this routine it adds to the previous one, I have tried to set the var undefined / null (which in themselves can be variables that are defined) and it still just adds the new results to the old ones, this is making the feature of regenerating a new name if you do not like the old one useless.

After writing this I realized my question is two part:

- How to do you delete a value from a var and restart?
- Is declaring your variables really that important?

I have yet to find any solid information on the difference between declared and undeclared other than it changes the inherent properties of the variables (mainly if a variable can be deleted or not)

```
var nameLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 3) + 3); /* min 3 max 13*/
testValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 3) + 3);
var compareLetter = 0;
var randomLetter = "";
var randomName = "";
var capitolLetter = "";
var checkLetter = 0;
var nameTitle = "XXX"; /* titles add _ between title and name*/
var nameLetters = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
    ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"],
    ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
];
if (nameTitle !== "") { /* my attempt to subtract title length +1 from name length if over 13*/
    nameLength = nameLength + (nameTitle.length + 1);
    if (nameLength > 13) {
        nameLength = nameLength - (nameLength - 13);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    randomLetter = nameLetters[compareLetter][Math.floor(Math.random() * nameLetters[compareLetter].length)];
    checkLetter = nameLetters[1].indexOf(randomLetter);
    if (checkLetter > -1) { /* my version of keeping consanants and vowels from stacking up */
        compareLetter = 2;
    } else {
        compareLetter = 1;
    }
    if (randomName.length < 1) { /* my version to keep first letter capitolized*/
        capitolLetter = randomLetter.toUpperCase();
        randomName = randomName + capitolLetter;
    } else {
        randomName = randomName + randomLetter;
    }
}
if (nameTitle !== "") {
    alert(nameTitle + "_" + randomName);
} else {
    alert(randomName);
}
alert("this is nameLength" + nameLength);
alert("this is testValue " + testValue);
delete nameLength;
delete testValue;
alert("this is nameLength" + nameLength);
alert("this is testValue " + testValue); /* notice this was not displayed*/
http://jsfiddle.net/OldGuyGamer/PJsZ3/4/
```

here is what I am working with, keep in mind that fiddle seems to GC after each run, the environment I am setting this up in does not do that.

Comment: It may be useful to show us a live example of your code, because right now your question is very vague and confusing. You should *always* declare your variables...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by delete and what do you mean by restart?

Comment: ok, let me get my fiddle copied over

Comment: @user3742773 you can use something like this in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/T45g6/

Comment: @user3742773 [Click the button here](http://jsfiddle.net/PJsZ3/5/). Notice how `nameLength` is not defined outside the scope of the `onLoad` function that JSFiddle wraps your code in?

Answer (score 2):

> I read if you declare a variable you can not delete it.

yes. e.g. 
var foo = 1; 
delete foo;
console.log(foo); // 1

BUT the thing to take a way is .. *do not delete a variable*

Only delete members. e.g. `delete  foo.bar`

Instead of deleting a variable you can reinitialize it to an empty state i.e. `foo = undefined`

Comment: I do not want to delete the variable unless I have no other choice, I really just want to delete is value, clean slate it.

Comment: @user3742773 setting it to undefined does it for you

Comment: i read that undefined should work, I also saw a function to keep undefined from ever being declared as anything else since I could accidentally end up as variable itself, and it does not work, I think the big problem expressing this issue is that the environment is not html. the environment is active once started, it never stops cycling, so I have it gen a name and wait x seconds for you to accept, then I asked it to clear the variable and restart, its not clearning

Answer (score 1):

> How to do you delete a value from a var and restart?

You can't delete declared global variables because ECMA-262 says they must be intialised as not deletable. You can't delete declared function variables because you can't access the "variable object" that they are attached to.

> Is declaring your variables really that important

Declaring variables constrains their scope to the current execution context. Not declaring a variable means that it becomes a property of the global object when the code assigning it a value is executed. If all variables are global, you start running into problems with name clashes, e.g. every counter in a for loop must be different in every loop in every function.

So if you want "deletable variables", then make them properties of some global object and you can treat them more or less like variables and delete them, e.g.

```
var u = void 0;
var globalObj = {varOne:u, varTwo:u, varThree:u};

delete globalObj.varOne;
```

You could do something similar using the global object like:

```
var globalObj = this;
varOne = varTwo = varThree = void 0;

delete globalObj.varOne;
```

I think the first approach is preferred, however you haven't provided enough detail to provide any objective analysis of which will suit your case better.

#### Edit

> I have yet to find any solid information on the difference between
>   declared and undeclared other than it changes the inherent properties
>   of the variables (mainly if a variable can be deleted or not)

Whether variables are declared or not also changes when the variable is initialised: with *var*, variables are created and initialised to *undefined* before any code is executed. Without *var*, variables don't exist until the code assigning to them is executed (which might be never if assignment is conditional).

Comment: I kept running to loop issues where the variable had already been declared or had not be declared and errors like i has already been declared, so I created a global variable and use it solely for all my loops, is that bad?

Comment: You should *never* get an error that a variable has already been declared. Multiple variable declarations are harmless (though they might be confusing and pointless).

Comment: talk to JSHint, it is the one who drove me to declaring all my variables globally to shut it up.

Comment: I assumed you were talking about syntax errors, such as those from a javascript compiler, not messages from a linter. They will report "errors" based on rules for coding standards that you can (usually) modify, or at least turn on or off, yourself.

Comment: not not a compiler, I really mean JSHint, put red dots next to all my for(var i = 0;i< x; i++) loops and started complaining that i had already been declared and then after I removed all the var from each one it did it again stating that they had not been declared, then after I declared one it put red dots next to each one and stated that i already have a value or something like that, so I just moved it to global changed the scope of i and never had that issue again.

Comment: so based off of what I am reading here, could I create a global.obj and put all my variables it in giving me full control of all my variables as far a deleting goes. and they still maintain global functionality.

Comment: @user3742773—yes. It means you have a few more characters to type but something like `gO` should be pretty safe, and `gObj` just fine.

Comment: would it be safe to say that after one is removed putting it back would be just as simple as re declaring it

Comment: "As simple as", yes (where that means creating and removing properties of an object is different to declaring a variable, but just as easy and can be used in the same way).